# Arrays in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

This is the controller function:

```
 public function tableMap()
{
         $nums = array("3","4","5","7");
            foreach ($nums as $num):
        $data['juns'] = $this->Hosting_model->djuns($num);
            endforeach;
        $data['tables'] = $this->Hosting_model->get_tables();
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('hosting/tableMap',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

This is the model function:

public function djuns($num)
{

```
        $this->db->select('clients.fullname');
        $this->db->from('tables');
        $this->db->join('clients', 'tables.phonenumber =clients.phonenumber', 'left');
        $this->db->where('num', $num);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->result_array();
```

}

I am trying to display the values array that returns from:

```
$data['juns'] = $this->Hosting_model->djuns($num);
```

When I display it in my view, I get only the last value that entered the array.
What am I doing wrong?

This part of code in my view:

```
foreach($juns as $jun):
 echo $jun['fullname'];
endforeach;
```

Comment: posting `Hosting_model->djuns` model code may helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, Loop overide the last entered element, So, you get only the last element.

```
foreach ($nums as $num):
    $data['juns'] = $this->Hosting_model->djuns($num);
endforeach;
```

Need your model code to give some suggestions.

**Edit** You can try [Vimal Rai' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61171430/12731030), And it will work ( echo in views will work)

You can do the following also

In the model

```
$this->db->select('clients.fullname');
$this->db->from('tables');
$this->db->join('clients','tables.phonenumber=clients.phonenumber', 'left');
$this->db->where_in('num', $num); //change where to where_in
$query = $this->db->get();

return $query->result_array()
```

In the controller, pass the array at once

```
$data['juns'] = $this->Hosting_model->djuns($nums); //no foreach loop and num -> nums
```

This will work as the above.

Comment: I added the model function.

Comment: Another question, in my view display foreach function, I need to display the values for each one of the number in nums, I mean separately. Can I do that?

Comment: You can access the values separately, `$jun["age"]` , `$jun["bday"]` like so.

Comment: Is there a way to make the juns inside the $data['juns'] in my controller an array so it could have his index or like enum that I could get my "3" results seperetly from the "4" results, I mean the  $nums = array("3","4","5","7");

Comment: As I understand your question, `$juns` is an array, (array of rows, row is an associative array), you can do this inside the loop `if ($jun["num"] == 3) ` and also can access directly `$juns[0]["firstname"]`

Answer (score 1):

You are remodifying the same value of an array. To insert all the values use it like this

```
$juns = array();

foreach ($nums as $num):
  $juns[] = $this->Hosting_model->djuns($num);
endforeach;

$data['juns'] = $juns;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes echo in the view will work but you can only echo the printable value like strings, int etc not arrays.